# BufferedReader.readline() returning null value

Tags: java, file, inputstream

I am creating this method which takes an `InputStream` as parameter, but the `readLine()` function is returning `null`. While debugging, inputstream is not empty.

```
else if (requestedMessage instanceof BytesMessage) {                    
    BytesMessage bytesMessage = (BytesMessage) requestedMessage;
    byte[] sourceBytes = new byte[(int) bytesMessage.getBodyLength()];
    bytesMessage.readBytes(sourceBytes);
    String strFileContent = new String(sourceBytes);                 
    ByteArrayInputStream byteInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(sourceBytes);
    InputStream inputStrm = (InputStream) byteInputStream;
    processMessage(inputStrm, requestedMessage);
}


 public void processMessage(InputStream inputStrm, javax.jms.Message requestedMessage) {
    String externalmessage = tradeEntryTrsMessageHandler.convertInputStringToString(inputStrm);
}

public String convertInputStringToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }

    br.close();
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: We can't really tell what's wrong from the given code. Please edit with a [minimal, but complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces this behavior.

Comment: This depends on your `inputStream`, which you did not share. Not to mention, you could just use `IOUtils.toString()` from `commons-io`.

Comment: how are you initialising the `inputStream`? Are you sure that the you are passing something valid to the `inputStream` so that the `readLine()` is not returning `null`?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try this,

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
```

i believe that raw data as it is taken is not formatted to follow a character set. so by mentioning UTF-8 (U from Universal Character Set + Transformation Format—8-bit might help

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are initializing and passing a valid InputStream to the function?

Also, just FYI maybe you were trying to name your function *convertInputStreamToString* instead of *convertInputStringToString*?

Here are two other ways of converting your InputStream to String, try these maybe?

1.

```
String theString = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, encoding);
```

2.

```
public String convertInputStringToString(InputStream is) {
    java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is, encoding).useDelimiter("\\A");
    return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
}
```

EDIT:
You needn't explicitly convert ByteArrayInputStream to InputStream. You could do directly:

```
InputStream inputStrm = new ByteArrayInputStream(sourceBytes);
```